# What is the true implementation logic of write()

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I know on linux, the kernel often caches read write access to disk, like the codes below, it save the `msg` to a buffer after the write call and return, then does the actual writing when the buffer is full.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main()
{
    int fd = open("./test.txt", O_RDWR, 0766);
    if (fd < 0) {
        printf("open file failed %d\n", errno);
        return -1;
    }
    
    char msg[100] = "write this msg to disk";
    write(fd, msg, strlen(msg));

    return 0;
}
```

I do not know the implementation of write(), my question is: If the buffer is in memory, the kernel copy the `msg` to buffer like `memcpy`, will such a copy be time-consuming?

Comment: No. It is faster than writing directly to disk since you can do fewer larger writes by caching than without.

Comment: That is the *point* of buffered i/o: not needing to go to the device for every operation.

Comment: @WeatherVane  So, does the underlying implementation of write include memcpy? in user-space or kernel space? I want to know it implementation, but I can find the source code except this https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/io/write.c

Comment: @YongqiZ there is write() glibc function which makes write() syscall which calls write operation in filesystem driver which schedules write operation for block device driver. There may be buffering/caching on all layers. Which implementation do you want to know?

Comment: @dimich The first step, after call `write(fd, msg, size)`, where does the system put `msg`? user-space memory or kernal-space memory? And how does the system put, use some function like `memcpy`?

Comment: You may find this blog post interesting: [The Journey of I/O from Userspace to Device](https://www.thegoodpenguin.co.uk/blog/demystifying-the-journey-of-i-o-from-userspace-to-device/).

Comment: For the actual syscall in the kernel, this source code is used: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/read_write.c#L646

Comment: @YongqiZ It depends (c). In some cases block device driver may program DMA to transfer data directly from user space buffer to device.

Comment: @lan Abbott It is really a good blog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; your buffer is copied into kernel memory before `write` returns; after that you can overwrite the buffer without affecting any background I/O involving the original data.

Copying the data consumes time; it's not free.

`write` is a generic function that works on any kind of file descriptor: you can write to a serial console, inter-process pipe, network socket, file, block device, ...

`write` has to look at the file descriptor and call to the right implementation for the device.

When you `write` some bytes to a file, those bytes overlap one or more blocks (equal sized units) of the file. If those blocks already exist, they have to be brought into memory and put into buffers. The buffers are then edited with the new bytes, and marked "dirty" (modified).

`write` requests do not align with blocks. They are often larger or smaller than blocks, and do not begin and end on block boundaries; writing is actually an editing activity which has to combine existing data with new data. When you write some bytes to a file, unless you write an exact block, some of the bytes written to storage will be bytes that didn't come from your program: such as zero padding bytes in the block if there is no other data, or existing bytes in the block that your `write` didn't touch.

Modified buffers have to be written to storage, though that action can be delayed. Delaying the action allows for optimization: like if that program (or any other) performs more `write` operations on the same blocks, then those edits can be incorporated before anything is actually written. Not to mention that the filesystem can *order* the writes in some way that makes it faster, like minimizing the head movements of spinning platter hard drive.

The key idea that flushing data from the operating system's buffers to the underlying file is generally not driven by buffers becoming full, but due to timer-based activity which monitors dirty buffers.

The `fsync` function can be used to delay the execution of a program until the previous writes on a file descriptor have been committed to storage (with certain documented caveats). The function possibly promotes the flushing as well (makes it happen sooner than it otherwise would).

Comment: I am a litter confuse in a `fork` multi process environment, the porcesses share the `File Table Entry` and the offset , How to ensure that the data is correct when the parent and child processes write at the same time?

Comment: @YongqiZ  The operating system doesn't ensure that the data is correct. That's up to the applications. The operating system will only protect itself from corruption of its data structures. Like when two writes go to the same buffer of the same file, it will make sure that the buffer object is not put into some inconsistent state that could destabilize the system. The writes from the two processes will be serialized or interleaved somehow, and that will be the result.  Processes that work with the same file destructively have to use file locking, or otherwise coordinate their activities.

Answer (score 0):

Copying in memory is faster than IO to disk. A disk IO is very slow, much slower than copying in memory.
(We can bypass the buffer to issue a disk IO directly in special cases. For example, there is a user-space buffer and you want to avoid copying it twice.)
With a kernel buffer, kernel can cluster and schedule the writes to issue fewer disk IO, issue large sequential IO, or even cancel some IO if the file is deleted.
If you use fwrite in libc, there is also user-space buffer to avoid trapping into kernel too frequently.

Comment: This isn't always the case, this is why there is `O_DIRECT`. You can be faster with in special applications where copying the data would consume to much time (but most of the time you don't).

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 I will edit the answer to mention this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According @Ian Abbott said, there is a very detailed analysis in [this blog](https://www.thegoodpenguin.co.uk/blog/demystifying-the-journey-of-i-o-from-userspace-to-device/)